# Toast freezes when calling runOnUIThread()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, toast

I just had an error on my application code: it said that I must call `Toast.makeText(...)` from the UI thread. I found that I should call this method with the `runOnUIThread(...)` method. That solved my problem but now the toast keeps freezing on my screen; any solution to this problem?

Comment: This is because your toast keeps showing and the reason is that your ui thread keeps running. Can you post code where you were getting error to must call Toast.makeText(..) from ui thread

Comment: yes post code.. multithreading? well it probably crashed..

Comment: Connect your device to the laptop and check the logs the app must have crashed. Post the code.

Comment: The problem is that the app doesn't crash

Comment: it's probably not freezing, you're most likely displaying it over and over again? could you please post some code surrounding the call to runOnUIThread